# Programmatically connect Silverlight to WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight

I have inherited a Silverlight application that consumes a WCF service, and is hosted in an ASP.NET web form. The application needs to run over HTTP and HTTPS, and will be installed on a customer's own server. The client code was originally generated using the Add Service Reference pointing to the locally-hosted service, so my ServicesReferences.ClientConfig obviously contains hard-coded references to localhost - not much use when deploying to another server, so obviously I need to be able to programmatically set the endpoint address that the client uses.

My code is currently:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
    {
        MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
    };
binding.Security.Mode = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.Scheme.StartsWith("https")
    ? BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport
    : BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;

var documentUri = HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri;
var builder = new UriBuilder(
        documentUri.Scheme,
        documentUri.Host, 
        documentUri.Port, 
        documentUri.LocalPath.Replace("hostpage.aspx", "MyService.svc"));

var client = new CustomerDetailServicesClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(builder.Uri));
client.ChannelFactory.Faulted += OnChannelFactoryFaulted;
client.DoSomething();
```

and while this works OK when I use HTTP, attempts to access via HTTPS fail with 404s for each call to the WCF service. Using Fiddler, I can see that it is only the URI scheme that is changing, and if I enter the HTTPS address of the service, I get the expected metadata page.

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: Not answering your question directly but FYI you can change the ServicesReferences.ClintConfig like any other App.Config or Web.Config. The Silverlight .xap file is just a WinZip file. You can extract the .ClientConfig modify it and then add it back to the Zip file. We did this all of time in my previous job, though you had to use WinZip (or one of the other Zip programs, not Windows Explorer Zip). From memory you had to also modify the file outside of the Zip package and then re-add it.

Comment: So as part of deployment, the installer would extract the .ClientConfig, set the correct endpoint addresses, and then zip it back up? Interesting...

Comment: Yep thats how we did it.

Answer (score 0):

*sigh* slap me with a wet herring. The HTTPS bindings for the web service had been commented out in web.config (since not all our customers can/want to run HTTPS on their servers, and having WCF bindings for HTTPS when IIS is not configured for HTTPS breaks WCF in lots of noisy ways).

It's amazing what fresh perspective and clarity a good night's sleep can bring to a problem.